# Hibernate Unidirectional OneToMany Relationship with Not-null Constraint in Foreign Key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables like this

[image: tables schema]

at first, i try to set `course_id` foreign key in `review` table to have **not null constraint** for the sake of data integrity.

So i create annotated class like for these two table like below:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private List<Review> reviews;

    public Course(){}

    public Course(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addReview(Review review){
        if(this.reviews == null){
            this.reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.reviews.add(review);
    }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "review_id")
    private int reviewId;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private int rating;

    public Review(){}

    public Review(int rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

and i create simple app to add review to an exsiting course like code below:

```
session.beginTransaction();

// get instructor from db
Course course = session.get(Course.class, 3);

// create review
Review review1 = new Review(4);

course.addReview(review1);

// save to db
session.save(course);

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

but this program will throw an error because it violates **not null constraint** i set in database before

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "course_id" violates not-null constraint

but if remove the **not null constraint** this program works fine because hibernate will execute insert with null value first than update the value like below:

```
Hibernate: insert into review (rating) values (?)
Hibernate: update review set course_id=? where review_id=?
```

is there a way for hibernate to insert directly with course_id value so i can keep the **not null constraint**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify in the mapping that the column is not `nullable`:

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false)
```

Comment: This made my day, thanks! ;)

Comment: You've made my day too!

Comment: You've made my day too! +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I wonder why this is necessary at all. I would have assumed non nullability to be the default here at least...

Comment: It's probably the most common scenario when using `@JoinColumn`; the attribute is defined using `boolean nullable() default true;`; and, Hibernate ORM doesn't know anything about the underlying database schema, unless is mapped accordingly. So, it just assumes that there is no constraint (based on the default value of the attribute).